# Can't either install or uninstall package via Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda

I've been trying to install the [openquake.engine](https://pypi.org/project/openquake.engine/) package via Anaconda. At first I got multiple errors one after another but [I thought] I fixed everything (pls see the P.S. for errors and solutions to them). Now, after going through all that, I get the following error:

```
openquake-engine 3.3.2 has requirement numpy<1.15,>=1.14, but you'll have numpy 1.16.2 which is incompatible.
osmnx 0.9 has requirement networkx>=2.2, but you'll have networkx 2.1 which is incompatible.
osmnx 0.9 has requirement requests>=2.21, but you'll have requests 2.20.1 which is incompatible.
```

First, it does not make sense as in PyPi the last released date of the package is Jan 22, 2019! Then here is the main issue: when I use `conda list`, `openquake.engine` is not listed!!

But when I run`pip install openquake.engine`, I get the following:

```
Requirement already satisfied: openquake.engine in c:\users\ameri19\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: numpy<1.15,>=1.14 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (1.14.6)
Requirement already satisfied: nose<1.4,>=1.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (1.3.7)
Requirement already satisfied: requests<2.21,>=2.20 in c:\users\ameri19\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (2.20.1)
Requirement already satisfied: scipy<1.2,>=1.0.1 in c:\users\ameri19\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (1.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: docutils<0.15,>=0.11 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (0.14)
Requirement already satisfied: mock<2.1,>=1.0 in c:\users\ameri19\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (2.0.0)
Requirement already satisfied: rtree==0.8.3 in c:\users\ameri19\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (0.8.3)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator>=4.3 in c:\users\ameri19\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (4.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: shapely<1.7,>=1.3 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (1.6.4.post2)
Requirement already satisfied: matplotlib<2.3,>=1.5 in c:\users\ameri19\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (2.2.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pyshp==1.2.3 in c:\users\ameri19\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (1.2.3)
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (40.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: h5py<2.9,>=2.8 in c:\users\ameri19\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (2.8.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq<18.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (17.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: django<2.1,>=1.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (2.0.13)
Requirement already satisfied: psutil<5.5,>=2.0 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (5.4.3)
Requirement already satisfied: PyYAML in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from openquake.engine) (3.12)
Requirement already satisfied: urllib3<1.25,>=1.21.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.21,>=2.20->openquake.engine) (1.22)
Requirement already satisfied: certifi>=2017.4.17 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.21,>=2.20->openquake.engine) (2018.11.29)
Requirement already satisfied: idna<2.8,>=2.5 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.21,>=2.20->openquake.engine) (2.6)
Requirement already satisfied: chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from requests<2.21,>=2.20->openquake.engine) (3.0.4)
Requirement already satisfied: pbr>=0.11 in c:\users\ameri19\appdata\roaming\python\python36\site-packages (from mock<2.1,>=1.0->openquake.engine) (5.1.3)
Requirement already satisfied: six>=1.9 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from mock<2.1,>=1.0->openquake.engine) (1.11.0)
Requirement already satisfied: python-dateutil>=2.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<2.3,>=1.5->openquake.engine) (2.6.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pytz in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<2.3,>=1.5->openquake.engine) (2017.3)
Requirement already satisfied: kiwisolver>=1.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<2.3,>=1.5->openquake.engine) (1.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyparsing!=2.0.4,!=2.1.2,!=2.1.6,>=2.0.1 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<2.3,>=1.5->openquake.engine) (2.2.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cycler>=0.10 in c:\programdata\anaconda3\lib\site-packages (from matplotlib<2.3,>=1.5->openquake.engine) (0.10.0)
```

Then, when I use `pip uninstall openquake.engine`, I get the following error:

```
Exception:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\base_command.py", line 179, in main
    status = self.run(options, args)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\commands\uninstall.py", line 75, in run
    auto_confirm=options.yes, verbose=self.verbosity > 0,
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_install.py", line 816, in uninstall
    uninstalled_pathset = UninstallPathSet.from_dist(dist)
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 496, in from_dist
    for path in uninstallation_paths(dist):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 50, in unique
    for item in fn(*args, **kw):
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\req\req_uninstall.py", line 67, in uninstallation_paths
    r = csv.reader(FakeFile(dist.get_metadata_lines('RECORD')))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1414, in get_metadata_lines
    return yield_lines(self.get_metadata(name))
  File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pip\_vendor\pkg_resources\__init__.py", line 1411, in get_metadata
    return value.decode('utf-8') if six.PY3 else value
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xe8 in position 152595: invalid continuation byte
```

Also, after I run `pip install openquake.engine`, it seems it automatically uninstalls the latest version of `numpy` and installs a former version that is compatible to `openquake.engine`, but then when I run something like `from openquake.hazardlib import const` I get the following error:

```
could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll
```

which is error #3 in the P.S. section below! And after I run `conda install -c conda-forge osmnx` to solve the issue, I start getting this error:

```
Something is wrong with the numpy installation. While importing we detected an older version of numpy in ['C:\\ProgramData\\Anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\numpy']. One method of fixing this is to repeatedly uninstall numpy until none is found, then reinstall this version.
```

So it seems like a deadlock! Dose anyone know how I could fix this?

**P.S. Errors and Solutions:**

*error #1: (occurred while using 'pip install openquake.engine' in Anaconda)*

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\temp\pip-install-mco6__1j\shapely\
```

*Solution to error #1:*

```
conda install -c conda-forge shapely
```

*error #2: (occurred while using 'pip install openquake.engine' in Anaconda, EVEN THOUGH I was running the prompt as administrator!!)*

```
PermissionError: [WinError 5] Access is denied
```

*Solution to error #2:*

```
pip install openquake.engine --user
```

Here, I got multiple *warnings*, but they did not seem to be that important! I tried `import epenquake.engine` in the Spyder and as it worked like a charm I thought it is all good (but it was not; see error #3)!

*error #3: (occured while running `from openquake.hazardlib import const`)*

```
could not find or load spatialindex_c.dll
```

*Solution to error #3:*

```
conda install -c conda-forge osmnx
```